# Make it possible for guests to add entries via "template-generated" form in expression engine?

Tags: codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm trying to figure out how if it is possible to provide guests (regular visitors) to my site with a form via the regular templates and let this form submission create an entry to a specified channel.

In essence, I would like to make a channel entry using a simple http-request and render a "frontend" response-page i suppose.

Does anyone know about any neat solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EE doesn't support this out of the box - all users must be logged in order to allow them to modify channels/weblogs

There's a few plugins - http://www.putyourlightson.net/projects/logmein is one of them that allow "fake" users being logged in

Mix that up with [SAEF](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/entry_form.html) and you might achieve what you want

Comment: Sounds like an interseting solution! Any other suggestions?

Comment: not as far as i'm aware ;) you could look in to the FreeForm extension. but this doesn't interact directly with channels. (I assume they remade FF for 2.0, still working with 1.7.x). You could probably do some kind of weird hack with FF and the Moblog module. But at least, from my experience, the above is the easiest way to achieve what you want.